# Dart - second time click event detect

Tags: dart

```
var modify = document.queryAll("#tab");

  for(var i=0; i<modify.length; i++)
  {
    modify[i].on.click.add((Event e) => show_content(i));
  }
// code for hide_content()
```

i have two function show_content() and hide_content() that operates on the div's
i'm not able to detect second time click on a div to trigger hide_content(). i've tried with a semaphore and - no luck

```
<div id="tab"> </div>
<div id="content"> </div>

<div id="tab"> </div>
<div id="content"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`queryAll` is used for non-unique elements. Using `queryAll` for an unique element with the ID `tab` doesn't make any sense. You should use `query('#tab')` where you get just a single `DivElement` as its return value.

However I'm not sure, I undersand your problem but if you need a toggle button, you're maybe looking for something like this:

```
DivElement uniqeDiv;

void toggle() {
 if(uniqeDiv.hidden) {
   // uniqeDiv.hidden = false;
   show();
 } else {
   // uniqeDiv.hidden = true;
   hide(); 
 }
}

void main() { 
  uniqeDiv = query('#tab');
  uniqeDiv.on.click.add((Event e) => toggle());
}
```

Comment: i have multiple div's with same id, every div has it's own content in a separate div

Comment: You can't have div's with the same `ID`. There are classes for this case.